# how does "bundle exec rake db:migrate" work if i have multiple databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

I am a newbie to rails/ruby.  i have two databases, sqlite for development/testing and postgres for production/deployment. when i run "bundle exec rake db:migrate", which database is updated with my current data model, the sqlite or the postgres?  the command output doesn't say much about the database it interacts with. ugh.  when i push up the code to heroku it doesn't work, so i'm assuming the database that is updated is sqlite.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database that is configured under your default environment (typically development).